# Is there any way to get average of average per category on power bi?

Tags: powerbi

This is the original data columns
[image: This is the original data columns]

This is the expected data columns where numeric_y column is the average of numeric_x column over core column, numeric is the average of numeric_y over p.area, avg is the average of numeric over p.index
[image: This is the expected data columns where numeric_y column is the average of numeric_x column over core column, numeric is the average of numeric_y over p.area, avg is the average of numeric over p.index]

Answer (score 0):

```
numeric_y = CALCULATE(AVERAGE([numeric_x]), FILTER( All('YOUR TABLE NAME'), [core] = EARLIER([core]) ) )
```